# How to get cluster subdomain in kubernetes deployment config template

Tags: templates, kubernetes, openshift

On kubernetes 1.6.1 (Openshift 3.6 CP) I'm trying to get the subdomain of my cluster using `$(OPENSHIFT_MASTER_DEFAULT_SUBDOMAIN)` but it's not dereferencing at runtime. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, docs show this is how environment parameters should be acquired. 
https://v1-6.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#container-v1-core

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  spec:
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          deploymentconfig: ${APP_NAME}
          name: ${APP_NAME}
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: myapp
          env:
          - name: CLOUD_CLUSTER_SUBDOMAIN
            value: $(OPENSHIFT_MASTER_DEFAULT_SUBDOMAIN)
```

Comment: Are you sure the environment variable is defined at the node level?

Comment: Good point; it's not! I was under the impression it was a standard environment parameter. How is it exported to make it available to pods?

Comment: Sorry have no idea, not using openshift

Comment: Whats your use case?

Comment: @user2983542 We want to inject subdomain info about the cluster because it reflects operating environment. Now that I think about it, we should probably use something else like "prod-useast", "nonprod-uswest", instead of the subdomain.

Comment: @raffian ok so thats not something that would get propagated to a Pod. It is unaware of the concept of a route which is OpenShift specific. Why not parameterise the yaml template and inject it in at creation time as appropriate? I'd probably move that out to a ConfigMap if it to be shared across multiple Pods

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set that value as an environment variable, this is the usage:

`oc set env <object-selection> KEY_1=VAL_1`

for example if your pod is named foo and your subdomain is foo.bar, you would use this command:

`oc set env dc/foo OPENSHIFT_MASTER_DEFAULT_SUBDOMAIN=foo.bar`